# xslt text disable-output-escaping

Tags: html, xml, xslt, cdata

Using XSL to create a HTML page from a XML I would like to know how to write a comment 
 in the resultant HTML page.

This is my XSL so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" ?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
        <![CDATA[<!--comment-->]]>
      </xsl:text>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It doesnt work, and it gives the next error:

```
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file mydirectoy/Myxsl.xsl line 4 element text
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

do it like this:

```
...
<xsl:comment>comment</xsl:comment>
...
```

You won't wrap it into `xsl:text` or `CDATA`. `xsl:comment` will create a comment node in the result tree. Here's the link to the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Comments